# How to share site-packages in different Anaconda python environments?

Tags: python, deep-learning, anaconda

I have used Anaconda to create two environments for deep-learning, for tensorflow-cpu and tensorflow-gpu, respectively. However,  when I need to import a site-package in codes, if I want to test these codes in both two environments, I need to pip install the site-package for them repeatedly, which I think is a waste of time and storage. 
So, how can I avoid it? Is there anyway to share the same site-package across different anaconda python environments?

Comment: *"used Anaconda to create two environments"*: Whats the benefit of doing so?

Comment: It is unclear why you need to pip install repeatedly, and what you mean by "import site-packages", as you should simply import modules as usual when using venv. In any case, why not create a single venv with all packages?

Comment: Sorry， I'm new to Anaconda, and I just use ```conda create -n python36 python=3.6``` to create environment. In my opinion, these created environments are independent because when I install a site-package under one environment, I can't use it when I activate the other environment and thus I need to install it again to use.

Comment: There is not a way to directly share the installed packages between environments. However, you should **not** pip install packages into conda environments unless absolutely necessary, you should use `conda install`. If you use `conda install` then conda will try to *hard-link* the files to save on storage space. Nonetheless, the whole point of the environments is that they are isolated, so you will have to conduct the install operation on both environments.

Comment: thank you, so I think the solution is that I should use conda install unless it can't work